# Continuity of solutions of Elliptic PDE with respect to parameters

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_\alpha$ satisfy
$$ \Delta u_\alpha+e^{u_\alpha}=\alpha f(x),   \ \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}^2$$
where $f$ is a fast decaying smooth function.

I would like to know how the solutions depend on $\alpha$. Is $u$ a continuous or differentiable function with respect to $\alpha$? I will also appreciate any reference.

Comment: Are you able to understand the one-dimensional case or the radial case in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I am not! However, I would appreciate any insight even for the radial case.

Comment: What do you know about the well-posedness theory for these equations?